# Some Images are broken and showing 508 error in console

Tags: php, ajax

I have a website in which I am loading the images using AJAX which is working fine for most of the images but some images are broken and I could not find the issue what's wrong with it. The image source is available and once you edit the source and revert back the same the image will show. Its showing 508 error in the console.

Below is the screenshot:-

https://prnt.sc/txjeib

https://prnt.sc/txjl29

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code with a minimum reproducible example

Comment: Copy and paste the piece of code in the post instead of adding snapshot

Answer (score 0):

It is because that your host or server is restricted, 508 error is for host restrictions. Call your host service provider. And if you use .htaccess file show it , it can be some issue with suffixes.